# Bar plot - plot many rows on one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Index | A | B | C | D | 
USA   | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
GER   | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
RUS   | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
GBR   | 4 | 5 | 4 | 5 |
```

(The values are not the true ones)
I want to make a bar plot for only the first 3 rows, where each "bar" is a variable (A, B, C, D) and the rows are shown like this example:

[image]

Where, for example, USA is blue, GER Is red and RUS Is green.
I tried using `matplotlib` and `seaborn`, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need filter first 3 rows by [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and then plot all 4 columns `A,B,C,D` by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.head(3).plot.bar(stacked=True, colors=['blue','red','green', 'pink'])
```

Or maybe you want transpose, so:

```
df.head(3).T.plot.bar(stacked=True, colors=['blue','red','green'])
```

Comment: What if it's not the first 3 rows? What if the 3 rows I want are not next to each other?

Comment: @user12195705 - Then select them by list like `df.loc[['USA','RUS','GER']].plot.bar(stacked=True, colors=['blue','red','green','pink'])`